# How can I use "RepoHeader" syntax when creating tutorial page?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I am a beginner to ROS documentation.

I am trying to create ros page which contains simple source code. (Stacks and packages)

There is quite convenient macro "RepoHeader" on ROSwiki.

I faced this message

"Once you've created your own *-ros-pkg repository, you can document your stacks and packages on ROS.org. Start by submitting your repository to be added to our index. You can do this by e-mailing ros-users."

I don't understand "You can do this by e-mailing ros-users". This means e-mailling to ros-users@code.ors.org with what contents?

Our repository is "bzr branch lp:cyphy" and is it possible to be indexed and use "RepoHeader"?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11182/how-can-i-use-%22repoheader%22-syntax-when-creating-tutorial-page?/) by [enddl22](https://answers.ros.org/users/194/enddl22/) on ROS Answers with karma: 177 on 2011-09-12

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your repo needs to be added to the public index.  If you announce it on the ros-users mailing list by emailing the details to ros-users@code.ros.org we will add it to the index of known public repos.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-09-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) on 2011-09-13**:
cyphy is now indexed: http://www.ros.org/wiki/cyphy

**Comment by [enddl22](https://answers.ros.org/users/194/enddl22/) on 2011-09-12**:
If we put new source code into our repository after indexing, then do we need to announce it again to add it to your list of index or automatically crawling code and add index?

**Comment by [enddl22](https://answers.ros.org/users/194/enddl22/) on 2011-09-12**:
I got it. Thank you. tfoote.

**Comment by [enddl22](https://answers.ros.org/users/194/enddl22/) on 2011-09-12**:
I got it. Thank you. tfoote.